# removing outliers from repeated dataframe in R

Tags: r

I would like remove outliers (remove rows with outliers) from each group (by each BRMA_Name)from a dataframe. My example data as following:

```
BRMA_No BRMA_Name   Price
1   A   5
1   A   6
1   A   100
1   A   90
2   B   50
2   B   60
2   B   40
2   B   400
2   B   4
3   C   4
3   C   2
```

I look through but could not find any answer (sorry), could anyone shed some light on it.

Kind regards
Lutfor

Comment: Can you share your desired output table?

Comment: How are you defining outliers? Use that calculation and check against each value and subset with that....

Comment: "outlier" is an artificial construct. Observations shouldn't be removed on the basis of being an outlier. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200534/is-it-ok-to-remove-outliers-from-data

Comment: I would like to define outliers if a data point is below Q1 – 1.5×IQR or above Q3 + 1.5×IQR

Comment: @LutforRahman stratum specific Tukey range or in aggregate?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
#outlier based on IQR - returns TRUE or FALSE based on the outlier condition
outlier <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x), 
         TRUE, 
         FALSE)
}

library(data.table)
#apply the function per group
setDT(df)[, out := outlier(Price), by = 'BRMA_Name']
df
# BRMA_No BRMA_Name Price   out
# 1:       1         A     5 FALSE
# 2:       1         A     6 FALSE
# 3:       1         A   100 FALSE
# 4:       1         A    90 FALSE
# 5:       2         B    50 FALSE
# 6:       2         B    60 FALSE
# 7:       2         B    40 FALSE
# 8:       2         B   400  TRUE
# 9:       2         B     4  TRUE
#10:       3         C     4 FALSE
#11:       3         C     2 FALSE
```

Then just select the rows where out is `FALSE` (e.g. `df[out == FALSE]`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `boxplot` to determine the outliers:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, rm := !Price %in% boxplot(Price, plot = FALSE)$out, BRMA_Name][(rm)]
#    BRMA_No BRMA_Name Price   rm
# 1:       1         A     5 TRUE
# 2:       1         A     6 TRUE
# 3:       1         A   100 TRUE
# 4:       1         A    90 TRUE
# 5:       2         B    50 TRUE
# 6:       2         B    60 TRUE
# 7:       2         B    40 TRUE
# 8:       3         C     4 TRUE
# 9:       3         C     2 TRUE
```

I suppose the more appropriate approach would be:

```
setDT(mydf)[, rm := !Price %in% boxplot.stats(Price)$out, BRMA_Name][(rm)]
```

From the help page for `boxplot.stats`, the function's default for the  `coef` argument is 1.5. If you wanted to change your outlier detection rule, you can change that value.

Answer (score 0):

Define the wrapper:

```
TukeyRangeFilter <- function(x) {
  normrange <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75)) + c(-1.5, 1.5) * IQR(x)
  findInterval(x, normrange)==1
}
```

Then loop across the elements of BRMA using `by`:

```
by(df, df$BRMA_Name, function(x) x[TukeyRangeFilter(x$Price), ])
```

Concatenate with `do.call(rbind, <output>)`.

```
     BRMA_No BRMA_Name Price
A.1        1         A     5
A.2        1         A     6
A.3        1         A   100
A.4        1         A    90
B.5        2         B    50
B.6        2         B    60
B.7        2         B    40
C.10       3         C     4
C.11       3         C     2
```